# How to obtain details of the statistical tests used in tbl_summary() from the getsummary package?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I need to provide details on the statistical tests used to calculate differences between the groups included in the analyses.

In the given example, could someone please guide me in obtaining the details of the Chi-squared and Kruskal-Wallis tests as presented in the table, without the necessity of running each test separately?

For instance, I need to report something such as: χ(4) = 299.55, p < .001.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
library(palmerpenguins)

penguins %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = species,
    missing = "no",
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} {sd}"),
    label = list(bill_length_mm = "Bill length (mm)")
  ) %>%
  add_p(
    all_continuous() ~ "kruskal.test",
    pvalue_fun = ~ style_pvalue(.x, digits = 3)
    ) %>% 
  bold_p()
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want the test statistics included in the table, or as values in your console? If in the table, do you want a separate column for chi square statistic and Kruskal-Wallis, or all in the same column?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the gtsummary merging function since the statistics and test df are included in the underlying table (but are hidden by default).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
library(palmerpenguins)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.2'

tbl <- 
  penguins |> 
  tbl_summary(
    by = species,
    missing = "no",
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} {sd}"),
    label = list(bill_length_mm = "Bill length (mm)")
  ) |> 
  add_p(
    all_continuous() ~ "kruskal.test",
    pvalue_fun = ~ style_pvalue(.x, digits = 3, prepend_p = TRUE)
  ) |> 
  bold_labels() |> 
  modify_column_merge(
    pattern = "X({parameter}) = {statistic}; {p.value}",
    rows = !is.na(p.value)
  ) |> 
  modify_fmt_fun(update = list(statistic = \(x) style_sigfig(x))) |> 
  modify_header(parameter = "**Test Result**")

tbl |> as_kable() # convert to kable to display on SO
```

| **Characteristic** | **Adelie**, N = 152 | **Chinstrap**, N = 68 | **Gentoo**, N = 124 | **Test Result** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **island** |  |  |  | X(4) = 300; p<0.001 |
| Biscoe | 44 (29%) | 0 (0%) | 124 (100%) |  |
| Dream | 56 (37%) | 68 (100%) | 0 (0%) |  |
| Torgersen | 52 (34%) | 0 (0%) | 0 (0%) |  |
| **Bill length (mm)** | 38.8 2.7 | 48.8 3.3 | 47.5 3.1 | X(2) = 244; p<0.001 |
| **bill_depth_mm** | 18.35 1.22 | 18.42 1.14 | 14.98 0.98 | X(2) = 225; p<0.001 |
| **flipper_length_mm** | 190 7 | 196 7 | 217 6 | X(2) = 245; p<0.001 |
| **body_mass_g** | 3,701 459 | 3,733 384 | 5,076 504 | X(2) = 218; p<0.001 |
| **sex** |  |  |  | X(2) = 0.05; p=0.976 |
| female | 73 (50%) | 34 (50%) | 58 (49%) |  |
| male | 73 (50%) | 34 (50%) | 61 (51%) |  |
| **year** |  |  |  | X(4) = 3.2; p=0.522 |
| 2007 | 50 (33%) | 26 (38%) | 34 (27%) |  |
| 2008 | 50 (33%) | 18 (26%) | 46 (37%) |  |
| 2009 | 52 (34%) | 24 (35%) | 44 (35%) |  |

```r
# print this table to see all the hidden and unhidden columns
#tbl$table_body
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-02 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>